# Mat show different in opencv2.4.10 on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, mat

In opencv's project,program as follow:

```
Mat A = Mat(9, 2, CV_16S );
int x0,y0;
ifstream fr("points.txt",ios::in);
for (int j=0; j<9; j++) {
            frs >> x0;
            frs >> y0;
            A.at<float>(j, 0) = x0;
            A.at<float>(j, 1) = y0;
        }
cout << A << endl;
```

but I got the output:

```
[0, -16080;
  0, 0;
  0, 16640;
  0, -16160;
  0, -16384;
  0, 16656;
  0, -16128;
  0, 16448;
  0, 16640]
```

accrually,the data in file `frs` is:

```
 -11 -8
  0  -6 
  8  -6 
 -7  -11 
 -2  -10 
  9  -10 
 -8  -14 
  3  -16
  8  -18
```

Did I have something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, name of input file stream is fr, but you trying to read points from frs.

[UPDATE]

You used wrong Mat type CV_16S instead of CV_32F. Here you can find more information. See Mat::depth.
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html

This code should work.

```
Mat A = Mat(9, 2, CV_32F);
float x, y;
std::ifstream fr("points.txt", std::ios::in);
for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    fr >> x >> y;
    A.at<float>(j, 0) = x;
    A.at<float>(j, 1) = y;
}
std::cout << A << std::endl;
```